# Adding new topics to Mirror maker configuration

Tags: apache-kafka

Currently, adding new topic(s) to mirror maker configuration needs a restart.
Wanted to see if there is an alternative approach available that allows doing the same without requiring a restart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a topic regex pattern instead of hard-coded values.

Or you can deploy a brand new config, rather than need to edit or cause a rebalance on an existing one, which will scale better.

Comment: Both scenarios will still require restart after configuration change so not sure I understand how it solves the issue?

Comment: No? Deploying brand new configs does not require restart of the old. And topic regex of `.*` will always capture new topics on the cluster without any restarts.