# Mirror maker2 takes long time to start

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

Currently, adding new topics requires restarting  mirror maker with the configuration update. So sometimes after doing that it's observed that it takes a long time for data to start moving from source to destination for the new topics.

Wondering why this might be happening and what are some possible options to avoid the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the same config, rather than starting new ones (with a different `group.id`) as I [answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74607288/adding-new-topics-to-mirror-maker-configuration), then, yes, the consumer group will need to rebalance and adding more and more topics into one consumer group without adding more consumer instances will be slower than less total topics.

Comment: Just to clarify adding more consumer instances to same consumer group can be done by starting a new MM2 instance(on same or different host) with same value of the property "name"(since group.id was MM1 configuration) and the topic list with new topics?
MM2 configuration reference: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-382%3A+MirrorMaker+2.0

Comment: You need to use a new group. Otherwise, adding a new MM2 config will cause a rebalance, and still be "slow". So a different `name`